# Not able to retrieve the output on jsp page using tiles framework

Tags: struts2, tiles2

I have created a project using struts2 and spring frameworks. Now I am trying to separate my dynamic content using tiles framework.
The layout consists of a header and body. The header in turn contains Welcome xyz (name of the logged user) and body part contains a tabular listing of people, populated from my database on startup.

### Following is my Tiles layout code

### **Layout.jsp**

```
<body>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
<tiles:insertAttribute  name="body"/>
</body>
```

---

### **tiles.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="welcome.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="addToListLayout" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="addEmployee.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

But after the login Iam getting the following output on jsp :-

---

welcome.jsp addEmployee.jsp

---

Can any one let me know why I am getting the names of jsp rather than the content?

Comment: how you integrating tiles with struts2? are you using the plugin and listener for this?

Comment: yes i have added the jars and listner

Comment: is it still giving same problem as its not clear from your comment

Comment: jars and listener were there in my code.

Comment: The problem is not yet solved

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that tiles is not interpreting your attributes as templates, it is interpreting them as strings.
From the [tiles doc](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertAttribute.html):

> This tag can be flexibly used to insert the value of an attribute into a page. As in other usages in Tiles, every attribute can be determined to have a "type", either set explicitly when it was defined, or "computed". If the type is not explicit, then if the attribute value is a valid definition, it will be inserted as such. **Otherwise, if it begins with a "/" character, it will be treated as a "template"**. Finally, if it has not otherwise been assigned a type, it will be treated as a String and included without any special handling.

So you can change your tag in tiles.xml to either this:

```
<put-attribute name="header" value="/welcome.jsp"/>
```

or this:

```
<put-attribute name="header" type="template" value="welcome.jsp"/>
```